# Криптосистема Мак-Элиса-Сидельникова

Tags: криптография

Нужна информация. Ничего понятного не нашёл, совсем чайник. Ищу алгоритм, советы по реализации и вообще реально ли её реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кого - нибудь будет интересовать эта криптосистема рекомендую посмотреть в сторону книг Сидельникова. Его криптосистема есть ничто иное как усовершенствованная криптосистема Мак - Элиса.